# AngulaJS ng-repeat input and sum

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make functionality using Angular js.The problem is that i get duplicate number for each input used ng-repeat and when i want calculate just one input and subtracted from some a number which i got early

```
<tr ng-repeat="myNumbers in allMyNumbers track by $index">
  <td><input type="number" ng-change="vm.allSum(myNumbers.inputSum)" ng-model="myNumbers.inputSum" ng-disabled="disable"></td>
            </tr>

vm.allSum = function (int) {
        vm.someNumb = 345
        vm.someNumb = parseFloat(vm.someNumb - int);
    };
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying duplicate number?

Comment: remove duplicates from array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.allMyNumbers = [{'inputSum':300},{'inputSum':200}]
      $scope.some_number  = 345
      $scope.enter_item ={}
      $scope.myFunc = function(obj,value) {
          obj.inputSum_new      = (value - $scope.some_number)
      };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="myNumbers in  allMyNumbers track by $index">
  orginal_value - {{myNumbers.inputSum}} ---------Enter_value - {{enter_item['val'+$index]||0}} -----Subtraction_val - {{some_number}}-----After subtraction result - {{'('+myNumbers.inputSum_new+')'}}<input ng-blur="myFunc(myNumbers,enter_item['val'+$index])"   ng-model="enter_item['val'+$index]" />

</div>
```

Comment: you do not use ng-change ..you have use ng-blur..and use  track by $index to avoid duplicate